# Business not appearing in Google Maps when searched by street address

Tags: google-maps

We run five businesses from a single physical address.  Each business has its own website and phone number. Each business relates to a different category (HVAC Contractor, Electronic Parts Supplier, Safety Equipment Supplier, Software Company, Building Equipment Supplier). Each business is listed, verified, published and up-to-date in Google My Business.

Three of the businesses (including our main/biggest business) are associated with one Google account.  The other two are each associated with their own Google accounts.

My problem is that one of the businesses, the main/biggest one, is NOT appearing in the 'At this location' list on Google Maps when searching for our street address.  This business does however appear just fine on Google Maps when searching for the business name or our primary search term ('HVAC controls').

According to [this (slightly old) answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/27188/1189), having multiple businesses at one address is no problem and they should all get listed in the 'At this location' panel on the left side of the page.  But that's not what we are finding.

The [Google My Business Guidelines](https://support.google.com/business/answer/3038177) only has info on multiple 'Individual practitioners' (e.g. doctors, lawyers, real estate agents) at a single location, but no info about multiple businesses at a single location.

Could the cause of the problem be having multiple businesses associated with one Google account?  Should each business have its own Google account?  Or have I missed something else that would be causing our main business to not be listed when searching by street address?

Answer (score 1):

One work around which has been found to work well for SEO is to use differing suite numbers at the same address...

EG:

Suite 1 222 Road Name Rd Town State Postcode - Business 1
Suite 2 222 Road Name Rd Town State Postcode - Business 2
...

This has been used by SEO companies for a few years now to deal with the issue of multiple businesses at one address under the same account.