# Google My Business not displaying in Google Maps Organics Results

Tags: local-seo, google-maps, google-local-search, google-places, google-my-business

I’m not sure what to make of this, but Google maps is not displaying my business ‘[BYBE](https://plus.google.com/+ByBeBournemouth/about?gmbpt=true&hl=en-GB&_ga=1.159818430.2060633695.1474318157)’ in Google Maps organic search results.

*The business is located on [Knyveton Road in Bournemouth](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Knyveton+Rd,+Bournemouth+BH1/@50.7245851,-1.8569555,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x48739f6128457737:0x9938af080fd56572!8m2!3d50.7245831!4d-1.8556509) yet is not listed for some reason:*

[image: Google Maps Knyveton Road Bournemouth]

*Yet, if I type BYBE, it displays, I have been on Google Places for many years, it used to work!:*

[image: Google Maps bybe flat 11 east cliff grange 35 knyveton road bournemouth dorset bh1 3qj]

---

I had many initial thoughts, what the problem could be, but later found evidence to debunk this, these were:

*Selective Niche*

- Perhaps Google will only returns certain niche’s on the map with no search term input? Sadly this is not true, since [my competitors are listed](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/32+Holdenhurst+Rd,+Bournemouth+BH8/@50.7231052,-1.8663196,18z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x4873a1de97d13745:0x7aef4c74d026e4f2!8m2!3d50.7231052!4d-1.8652253) under the same niche (website designer), yet they can be found easily several roads down from my business address.

*Hours of Opening*

- Could it possibly be that my business is closed when looking on Google Maps? Sadly, no, since many other businesses are closed yet display fine, also again, in the same niche.

*Flat, Suite, Block*

- Maybe Google is not returning the location search results, because its registered under a address with a 'flat number'? but then Google again, I'm lend to believe that Google prefers businesses to use exact address, as I could put the street address, but this doesn't help my customers too much...

*Google Reviews*

Maybe you need a certain amount of reviews perhaps? Nope, [I have more reviews than a lot of the other web design agencies](https://www.google.com/search?ludocid=9049327804541505906&hl=en-GB&q=BYBE%20Flat%2011%2C%20East%20Cliff%20Grange%2035%20Knyveton%20Road%20Bournemouth%20BH1%203QJ&_ga=1.252616842.2060633695.1474318157) in Bournemouth, and they can be found again with ease.

*I deliver goods and services at their location*

- The other possibility I’m left with is because I have checked the box the following boxes:

  - I deliver goods and services to my customers at their location [X]
  - I also service customers at my business address [X]

So, I have checked both, meaning customers can come and go, to and from my business address, 95% of my work is actually done at my business and regularly have customers served at my business address, the 5% is meeting new customers, since I like to learn more about them, in their environment, so I can actually grasp what they are about.

*Note(s):*

I’m aware of a [similar question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91808/business-not-appearing-in-google-maps-when-searched-by-street-address) however this question focuses on multiple businesses, or individuals operating under the same address, this is not the case, this is one business, and I'd like to know more specificity why Google may not display this data, rather than solving just my issue which won't help anyone else.

*Question(s):*

What reasons are there for Google My Business not being listed organically, without a search input on Google Maps?

Comment: Hhhmmm, I see a similar thing in my area. In fact, _a lot_ of small businesses, that previously appeared, no longer "just" appear on the map (is this what you call "organic results"?) - unless you specifically search for the appropriate business category. Very few small business "just" appear now. In fact, some of those that do appear, don't seem to have been "claimed"?

Comment: Have you had much help from the Google support team?

Answer (score 1):

i never ever seen, that Google shows a local business without a house number in search query. However, if i type a house number in, Bybe is well displayed:
[image]